# é possivel usar query nativa + spring data para fazer paginação?

Tags: query, oracle, paginação, spring-data

Preciso fazer uma paginação usando querys dinamicas porque tenho que fazer muitos joins, estou tentando fazer somente um `select *` para testar o uso da query nativa + spring data, mas a mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
Cannot use native queries with dynamic sorting and/or pagination in method public abstract
```

Segue o código:

```
@Query(value = "select i.* " + "from VRS.TB_CLIE_INVS i ",nativeQuery = true)
Page<TbClieInv> testePaginacaoQuery(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Banco de dados Oracle, a  minha aplicação é Restfull usando spring boot, no nosso back, e front é Angular, estou usando o JpaRepository, quando uso o findAll do JpaRepository funciona, mas quando tento usar com @query ele não sobe o projeto de maneira nenhuma, não é possível que eu só consiga paginar com os métodos pré definidos do JpaRepository, tenho Joins enormes entre muitas tabelas que só fazendo com query dinamica mesmo, por enquanto estou buscando informações na internet mas ainda não achei uma saída.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM VRS.TB_CLIE_INVS /*#pageable*/",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM VRS.TB_CLIE_INVS",
       nativeQuery = true)
Page<TbClieInv> testePaginacaoQuery(Pageable pageable);
```

---

**Fonte:** [SOen - Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42150896/664577)

Comment: código correto executou com sucesso, Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou !!!!!

funcionou exatamente desse jeito sem o order by, o intuito era simular o Page findAll do PagingAndSorting e o teste foi executado com sucesso, eu já tinha tentado fazer com o count assim como vc me passou mas a chave dos meus problemas realmente era colocar esse comando `/*#pageable*/"`, acho que agora com esse vou conseguir converter as outras querys dinamicas que tenho para com paginação, muito obrigado pela ajuda, segue o código que funcionou:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tabela1 /*#pageable*/",  
       countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM tabela1",
       nativeQuery = true)
Page<ClassemodeloTabela> testePaginacaoQuery(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Oi Leandro, formatei seu código e atualizei minha resposta para refletir seu comentário. Você pode marcar uma resposta como correta aceitando-a e indicar que ela é boa com um voto positivo ([faça um tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)) .  Você realmente quis escrever uma resposta para sua pergunta ou sua intenção era apenas comentar na minha resposta? No segundo caso você poderá fazer isso assim que tiver 50 pontos de reputação, devido ao formato do site respostas e comentários são coisas distintas e não devemos usar respostas para comentar.

Comment: não consegui colar como resposta porque deu comprimento excedido, apesar de ler faz anos, mas é a primeira vez que posto aqui, tentei responder seu comentário mas tem limitações de linhas, por isso coloquei abaixo para visualização geral, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que você quebrou a barreira do primeiro post ;). Vou sinalizar para os moderadores para ver se eles conseguem converter a resposta em comentário (como o código ficou o mesmo acho que o resto cabe).

Comment: eu estou com grandes duvidas de sintaxe para fazer esse select com paginação e usando o join, isso é possível ?